# What is the REST standard (create and update) for return?

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

This issue of standards for REST architecture is quite confusing. Some say there is no pattern for the create and update operation, others say the pattern is to return the created object. Which would be correct?

Comment: I would (assuming there was no special circumstances around the calls), return CREATED with a Location and ETag header for POST, and an ACCEPTED with an updated ETag header for PUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue of standards for REST architecture is quite confusing. Some say there is no pattern for the create and update operation, others say the pattern is to return the created object.

This is true, it is confusing.

Technically, [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) isn't an architecture, but rather an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5), which is to say a set of architectural constraints.

The world wide web is the reference application for REST, by which I mean it is the most widely known application built to satisfy the REST architectural constraints ([mostly](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4)).

REST doesn't have standards of its own, it just says that you should have standards if you want a successful long-lived web-scale application.

The web has standards; in particular, it has the HTTP standard, which is how the web satisfies the self-descriptive messages constraint of the REST architectural style

The current HTTP standard for semantics and content is RFC 7234; in particular, [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) describes how status codes semantics relate to the response payload, and section 6.3.1 describes the various payloads returned when a request is successful.

The framing I find easiest to understand: HTTP tells us how the server should respond when a client's attempt to create, update, or delete a web page is successful, and therefore (because the interface is uniform) it also describes how we should respond when those same message semantics are applied to "resources" that are NOT web pages.

When you look at the semantics for responses after a successful PUT or POST, it may not seem immediately helpful.  What the language of the standard actually says is that you can return a copy of the resource (technically - a copy of a representation of the resource), or not -- and that you use particular metadata ([Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2)) to signal that the payload is a representation of some resource.  When the Content-Location value matches the effective request URI, "everybody knows" that the payload of the response is a new representation of the resource that was the target of the request.

In conclusion: "you MUST return the resource" is wrong.  You MAY return the resource, and when you do that you SHOULD include the appropriate metadata in the response so that general purpose components know that's what's going on.  You MAY also decide to return something else (you can even return [nothing at all](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)), in which case the metadata signally that the returned entity is a representation of the resource would NOT be appropriate.

---

A fair amount of the confusion comes from sources *outside of REST and HTTP*.

For instance, consider [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/); the section on [creating resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating) may sound familiar

> The response MUST also include a document that contains the primary resource created.

If you are in an environment where people assume that REST is JSON:API, or even that REST is JSON plus HTTP, then this reads to be a very strong claim about REST.  But it isn't, because REST isn't limited to those things.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, it depends on your Use-Case and other factors like eg Network Traffic.
On a POST I would return in most cases at least the ID of the created resource. But if you have some Measurements eg from an IoT device, this device does not care about the Resource nor its ID in your application.
Pretty much the same is true for a PUT. Is the update happening directly, is the resource changed at all during N update in your App?
I guess there is no real Standard, and depends on your Use Case.